# Unexpected REST mapping with Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

In Test Case #3 below, I'm landing in an unexpected method.  Is there a better mapping strategy?

```
@Path("/pets")


@GET
@Path("/{petId}")       
public Response getPet(@PathParam("petId") String petId){ 
    //fetch a single pet record
}

@GET
@Path("/owner/{ownerId}")   //fetch collection of pet records for an owner
public Response getPetListByOwner(@PathParam("ownerId") String ownerId){ 
    //fetch a list of pet records by ownerId
    //Validate ownerId not null...
}
```

### Test Case #1

/pets/123
//Correctly invokes getPet("123")

### Test Case #2

/pets/owner/456
//Correctly invokes getPetListByOwner("456")

### Test Case #3

/pets/owner
//**Unexpectedly** invokes getPet().  Jersey is using "owner" as the petId for getPet(), and invokes getPet("owner").  I expect the code to invoke getPetListByOwner() where I can have a null check and return a response that ownerId is required, but I'm landing in the wrong method (getPet()).   While I actually don't want folks to hit this URL, I cannot stop them.  And I don't want searches for a pet executed with the petId="owner" either.  
*Is there a better mapping strategy?*

Answer (score 0):

Define another endpoint method explicitly mapped to path `/owner` (with no additional path arguments) and return the error response from there.

```
@GET
@Path("/owner")
public Response getPetListByOwner() {
    return Response
            .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .build();
}
```

Alternatively, you could achieve it with just one endpoint method and some regular expression matching against the path template to declare that the portion after `/owner` is optional.  The [Java EE6](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/ginpw/) tutorial has information about usage of regular expressions in `@PathParam` templates.

I prefer the readability of declaring the extra endpoint method explicitly, but this is somewhat subjective.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are declaring the path parameter as a String. Instead, declare it as an int.

The code should look like

```
@Path("/pets")


@GET
@Path("/{petId}")       
public Response getPet(@PathParam("petId") int petId){ 
    //fetch a single pet record
}

@GET
@Path("/owner/{ownerId}")   //fetch collection of pet records for an owner
public Response getPetListByOwner(@PathParam("ownerId") int ownerId){ 
    //fetch a list of pet records by ownerId
    //Validate ownerId not null...
}
```

Then you will not encounter the problem of `order` being recognized as an ID